# Packaging a node-webkit app (exe) to Win 8.1 appx

Tags: windows-8.1, executable, node-webkit

I am attempting to transform a built node-webkit app that I created into an executable appx Win 8.1 Metro App.

After creating my appx package and signing it, and creating my AppxManifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
    <Identity Name="bouveret" Version="1.0.0.0" Publisher="CN=Mc" />
    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>iMotion</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>XXX</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>logo.png</Logo>
    </Properties>
    <Prerequisites>
        <OSMinVersion>6.2.1</OSMinVersion>
        <OSMaxVersionTested>6.2.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
    </Prerequisites>
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="fr" />
    </Resources>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="bouveret" Executable="bouveret.exe" EntryPoint="WinMain">
            <VisualElements DisplayName="iMotion" Logo="logo.png" SmallLogo="logo.png" Description="iMotion" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#000000" ToastCapable="false">
                <DefaultTile ShowName="allLogos" ShortName="iMotion" WideLogo="logo.png" />
                <SplashScreen Image="logo.png" />
                <InitialRotationPreference>
                    <Rotation Preference="portrait" />
                </InitialRotationPreference>
            </VisualElements>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</Package>
```

I manage to install it via Powershell, but I suspect it doesn't manage to run the entry point for the app. NW apps don't have a C# interface I can use to set a proper entry point.

Anyone has any idea on which entry point should be set? The executable launches itself properly, but the appx package doesn't launch anything : I see the logo on a black background and then it minimizes itself to the desktop without any debug trace.

Thank you.